# How do I get Rails, SSL and Apache to play nice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, https

Trying to get my Rails app submitting some sensitive form data with SSL and not having too much luck. The basic problem is that once I submit a form (this is on a POST request), it just hangs for a minute and then says the server is not responding.

Here's what I'm working with:

Apache 2.2.3
Rails 2.3.8
RedHat Linux (Rackspace server)

Using the **ssl_requirement** plugin as follows:

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SslRequirement
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details

  # Scrub sensitive parameters from your log
  filter_parameter_logging :password
end
```

Controller I want to use SSL on an Action:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  ssl_required :create
  ...
end
```

My httpd.conf includes this line to grab ssl.conf:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

And my SSL VHost (in the conf.d/ssl.conf file) looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443>
   ServerName www.nameofmyapp.com
   ServerAlias nameofmyapp.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/myapp/current/public
   RailsEnv production
   RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/2012-nameofmyapp.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/2012-nameofmyapp.com.key
   SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/SecureSite_Bundle.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost.localdomain' does NOT match server name!?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done, and it works great (although this is OS X, not Linux)

http://web.archive.org/web/20120919184321/http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Setting-up-an-SSL-enabled-Apache-development-server-using-Phusion-Passenger-on-OS-X-Snow-Leopard